# Should I say the real reason as to why I've left the company

Tags: interviewing

Leaving company because I don't think the way they solved things was professional, ranging from how they dealt with clients to how certain in office issues were solved. My boss and colleagues were great but I wasn't happy with the rest.
That's of course not the only reason why I'm leaving.

It was my first internship and they wanted me to continue working, but I've decided not to.

Next time I'm in an interview, in case this comes up, should I mention this? Should I go into detail as to why I've left the company? I don't want it to seem as if I had no reason and I do think want to go lengths lying as to why I've left it.

EDIT: What exactly should I say when asked why I left it? I feel anything I say I should be able to back up and also they will probably call the company to check out. I should graduate in 3 years.

Comment: No, never talk bad about previous employers.

Comment: did you leave during your internship or did your internship simply come to an end and decided not to come back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is actually pretty easy for you. Your internship had a limited term on it. While they wanted to sign you up for another round, this is not the same as leaving a job or position.  Your internship was done, and you moved on after it was completed.

Quite simply, you list it for what it was on your resume - a six month, one year, whatever internship.  No one in the world is going to say "wait, why didn't you stay after your one-year internship was done?"

They MIGHT ask "did you have the chance to stay with the company?"  To which you honestly reply "Yes, I did" (hence, you were good enough that they wanted you to stay), ".... but I was interested in gaining other experience..."

Internships pay like crap compared to full-on hires because the trade-off is valuable real-life work experience.  If the intern is in it for the experience, no one even blinks if interns move on to gain more and different experience elsewhere. No red flags will be raised, and you won't be in a position to have to explain tactfully that they were kind of jerks, in your opinion. The internships are there for young professionals to try out experiences and for companies to get relatively cheap labor from people who are talented and ambitious. Your experience (of moving on) will be viewed as completely normal.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I go into detail as to why I've left the company?

**No**, you should not.

I would suggest keep your reason for leaving *vague* and simple.  You could say something like:

"*There were no growth opportunities for me*" 
or  
"*the internship was coming to an end*"
as examples. 
 
Your instincts are correct, do not **lie**, but you do not need to go into details here either.

**Never, ever, ever** bad mouth a previous boss or company (**internship or regular employment**) as it is almost always considered in poor taste to any potential suitors you may have, and may cost you the opportunity.

Comment: the OP didn't leave just dent extent the internship - totally diferent

Comment: No, @Neuromancer its not.  They may not have been an employer, but they did work for them.  There is nothing to gain by talking badly about them.

Comment: err no the op doesn't have to say any other than my suggestion in my answer

Comment: @Neuromancer you don't even answer the question completely....

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking this, an internship is not a job as such.

You just say "after interning with Acme co and learning valuable real world experience I am now looking for my first full time position"

I am assuming you have graduated

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer to your stated question: no.  Speaking poorly of former partners, employers or acquaintances very rarely holds any real upside to you, no matter how cathartic it may seem.

As an aside, it seems fairly common for driven individuals to seek out varied internships while in school.  The reason being they are interested in the industry they are entering. Gaining a broader exposure to the industry through varied internships allows them to more fully explore the industry and perhaps get a better idea of what particular field they would like to pursue.

If you are ever pressed for a reason why you left that company, something along the lines of the above paragraph should suffice.  It shows awareness, drive, passion and steers the conversation in a positive direction.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated it is really bad practice to say negative things about your previous employer, the people, the processes or the environment. Doing that is really like burning the bridge so to speak. You never know when things will come back and cause a backlash for you.

If you are asked why you are leaving the best approach is to make it about you. Explain why the change is good for you and how it fits into your set goals. The explanations should be forward looking relative to the new situation you are considering. You should not try to reference the previous employer in any way that could be seen as negative. Even saying something like "there is no possibility of advancement" at the company you are leaving can be seen as a negative.